# How to determine which app caused an intent to start?

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I'm working on an Application that should determine which app caused an **Intent** to start. I tried different ways, At last I used Android's AccessibilityService. All Window changed can be retrieved from this service.

The main part of my question is: An App receives a broadcast (Like sending JSON data from firebase or...) and app launches the specified packageName from the data received I can Determine how to know which package is launched but not the launcher of the package

**A bit more explanation:**
We have 2 apps with packages: **com.app.a, com.app.b**. App com.app.a receives broadcast with JSON data → App com.app.a launches another package specified in JSON (e.g. com.android.settings)

The problem is here that com.app.b can determine com.android.settings is launched but can't access who launched it. I tried AccessibilityService **WindowsChanged,WindowStateChanged** but no success.

Comment: Since you wrote `com.app.a` and `com.app.b`, have `com.app.a` tell `com.app.b` what it is doing.

Comment: @CommonsWare The packages were examples both of them can change every time

Comment: You wrote `com.app.a`, because you control its functionality ("receives broadcast with JSON data → App com.app.a launches another package specified in JSON"). You wrote `com.app.b`, because you control its functionality ("com.app.b can determine com.android.settings is launched but can't access who launched it"). Since you wrote `com.app.a` and `com.app.b`, have `com.app.a` tell `com.app.b` what it is doing.

Comment: If you did not write `com.app.a` (but merely reverse-engineered it), and you are trying to spy on what `com.app.a` is doing, that hopefully is not possible (other than perhaps on rooted devices), for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think my explanation was not good enough. our app is com.app.b and only we have access to it , i want to com.app.b be notified when an app launches another app (e.g. com.app.a opens org.telegram.messenger to share an item , com.app.b can receive org.telegram.messenger launch but can't get packagename of launcher(com.app.a))

Comment: And, as I wrote, hopefully that is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons. Even finding out that `org.telegram.messenger` launched is a privacy and security flaw, one that Google has been progressively limiting with each new Android release since Android 5.0. Malware authors *love* to know when apps are launched so that they can interpose their own UI (tapjacking and activityjacking attacks).

Comment: You can only use Accessibility Services to deduce this information indirectly. As in, whichever package was active before a window change event, vs whichever package is active afterward.

Comment: @ChrisCm Thanks, Can you please provide a code example or Related Class/Method to get active app before & after event? And one other point the app that launches has no window and process is done in broadcast.

Comment: The code example I would supply would not answer this question (only this questions intent), if you update your question to be more "generic" in terms of what you're trying to accomplish rather than how, so that my answer would be applicable without the context in these comments being necessary, I would do so happily. But, the link between the code I can supply, and this question, is not clear without context. Which is rough. I leave to you to ask another question or edit this one at your discretion. Also, I have the code in a laptop at my office, so I need to stall a bit anyway ;).